# How to add class via Javascript instead of work with css inside js code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a sidenav menu. I want to work on the style directly in the css file instead of the Javascript code as below.

For example: dropContent.style.display === "block" and "none", I wish there was a class to modify and not add css values inside the js code. Is this possible ?

References: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_dropdown

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

  for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("activate");
  
  var dropContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (dropContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `classList.add('class-name')`? But I guess you want `classList.toggle('class-name')` so you dont need an if/else-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

In your JS:

```js
if (element.classList.contains("hidden")) {
  element.classList.remove("hidden");
} else {
  element.classList.add("hidden");
}
```

Make sure your element has the display property `block` to start with and I believe this should give you what you want.

Edit: As @tacoshy points out, there's the toggle function, which is much clearer:

```js
element.classList.toggle("hidden");
```

Comment: just use `toggle` instead of an if/else-statement

Comment: @tacoshy good point, that's a neat function I didn't know about. Answer updated

Comment: I deleted else and added `element.classList.toggle ("hidden");` but it's not working. Instead it works fine as suggested by @JoeHerbert in the first example.

Comment: @Snorlax they should both work. Note the toggle line replaces the whole JS code I posted, not just the else section.

Comment: @JoeHerbert Sorry, I did it differently and I realized I was wrong. Now it works: `var element = this.nextElementSibling; element.classList.toggle ("hidden");`